# Message coming from wrong user during private and group chat

Tags: node.js, angular, quickblox

We are integrate Quickblox chat application in our project. We are using Node Js in backend and Angular 7 in frontend. We are already implemented both private and group chat. One to one private chat is okay but we are facing problem in below scenario -

One to one private chat

1. Three different user logged in from three different machine. when the other two users tried to me message one user like A and B tried to message C then last message replaced by any of user A or B. Ex A write a message to C its showing message coming from  A but when B write a message to C its showing message coming from A instead of B. We will check the chat section in Quickblox admin panel its also showing wrong.

Group chat

1. The above mentioned scenario happened in group chat also. Message replaced by wrong user.
   Please help us to sort out the problem we are facing.